# Find the inrush current in the capacitor

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, coil, math, inrush-current

How can I find the inrush current value of the capacitor in the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCTRAq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When \$R_1=R_2=10\$ and \$L=10mH\$ and \$C=1\mu F\$ and \$V_1=1\$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's homework with no attempt to solve.

Comment: I’m closing this question because it is a homework/assignment type of question with no attempt at a solution or explanation of what the OP understands. Homework type questions are permitted but need to show some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRRBfV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can solve for \$\text{V}_2\$:

$$\text{V}_2=\frac{\text{R}_3\text{R}_4\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)+\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\tag4$$

Using \$(2)\$, we can see that:

$$\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{R}_4\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)+\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\tag5$$

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

- $$\text{R}_2=\text{sL}\tag6$$
- $$\text{R}_3=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\tag7$$
- The input voltage is a stable DC voltage equal to \$\hat{\text{u}}\$, so:
  $$\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}\tag8$$

So, we get:

$$\text{i}_3\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_4}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{sL}\right)+\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_1+\text{sL}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)}=$$
$$\frac{\hat{\text{u}}\text{R}_4\text{C}}{\text{CL}\text{R}_4\text{s}^2+\left(\text{L}+\text{C}\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\right)\text{s}+\text{R}_1+\text{R}_4}\tag9$$

It is not hard to show that when \$x:=\left(\text{L}+\text{C}\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\right)^2-4\text{C}\text{L}\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_4\right)>0\$ we get the behavior that you're talking about (with just one maximum).

Now, when we use inverse Laplace transform we can see:

$$\text{I}_3\left(t\right)=\frac{2\hat{\text{u}}\text{CR}_4\exp\left(-\frac{\left(\text{L}+\text{CR}_1\text{R}_4\right)t}{2\text{CLR}_4}\right)\sinh\left(\frac{t\sqrt{x}}{2\text{CLR}_4}\right)}{\sqrt{\text{L}^2+\left(\text{CR}_1\text{R}_4\right)^2-2\text{CLR}_4\left(\text{R}_1+2\text{R}_4\right)}}\tag{10}$$

The maximum occurs when (if we obey the condition \$0<x<\text{L}+\text{CR}_1\text{R}_4\$):

$$\hat{t}=\frac{\text{CLR}_4\ln\left(\frac{\text{L}+\text{CR}_1\text{R}_4+\sqrt{x}}{\text{L}+\text{CR}_1\text{R}_4-\sqrt{x}}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}\tag{11}$$

And at that time \$\hat{t}\$ we have a current of:

$$\text{I}_3\left(\hat{t}\right)=\frac{2\hat{\text{u}}\text{CR}_4\exp\left(-\frac{\left(\text{L}+\text{CR}_1\text{R}_4\right)\hat{t}}{2\text{CLR}_4}\right)\sinh\left(\frac{\hat{t}\sqrt{x}}{2\text{CLR}_4}\right)}{\sqrt{\text{L}^2+\left(\text{CR}_1\text{R}_4\right)^2-2\text{CLR}_4\left(\text{R}_1+2\text{R}_4\right)}}\tag{12}$$

> Using your values, we get:
>
> $$\hat{t}=\frac{\text{arccoth}\left(\frac{101}{\sqrt{9401}}\right)}{500 \sqrt{9401}}\approx0.0000401357\space\text{s}\tag{13}$$
>
> And:
>
> $$\text{I}_3\left(\hat{t}\right)=\frac{\left(\sqrt{9401}+101\right) e^{-\left(1+\frac{101}{\sqrt{9401}}\right)\text{arccoth}\left(\frac{101}{\sqrt{9401}}\right)}}{4000}\approx0.000931611\space\text{A}\tag{14}$$
>
> With:
>
> $$x=\frac{9401}{100000000}\approx0.00009401>0\tag{15}$$

[image]

If you're a user of [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica), you can use the codes that I wrote to solve this question:

```
In[1]:=R2 = s*L;
R3 = 1/(s*c);
Vi = u/s;
FullSimplify[
 InverseLaplaceTransform[(R4 Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4), 
  s, t]]

Out[1]=(2 c E^(-(((L + c R1 R4) t)/(2 c L R4))) R4 u Sinh[(
  Sqrt[-4 c L R4 (R1 + R4) + (L + c R1 R4)^2] t)/(
  2 c L R4)])/Sqrt[L^2 + c^2 R1^2 R4^2 - 2 c L R4 (R1 + 2 R4)]

In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I3 + I4, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I1 == (V1 - V2)/R2, 
   I3 == V2/R3, I4 == V2/R4}, {I1, I3, I4, V1, V2}]]

Out[2]={{I1 -> ((R3 + R4) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4), 
  I3 -> (R4 Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4), 
  I4 -> (R3 Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4), 
  V1 -> ((R3 R4 + 
      R2 (R3 + R4)) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4), 
  V2 -> (R3 R4 Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4)}}

In[3]:=R2 = s*L;
R3 = 1/(s*c);
Vi = u/s;
L = 10*10^(-3);
c = 1*10^(-6);
u = 1;
R1 = 10;
R4 = 10;
FullSimp
FullSimplify[
 InverseLaplaceTransform[(R4 Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4), 
  s, t]]

Out[3]=(E^(-500 (101 + Sqrt[9401]) t) (-1 + E^(
   1000 Sqrt[9401] t)))/(10 Sqrt[9401])

In[4]:=FullSimplify[Solve[{D[%3, t] == 0, t > 0}, t]]

Out[4]=ArcCoth[101/Sqrt[9401]]/(500 Sqrt[9401])

In[5]:=FullSimplify[Limit[%3, t ->ArcCoth[101/Sqrt[9401]]/(500 Sqrt[9401])]]

Out[5]=((101 + Sqrt[9401]) E^(-(1 + 101/Sqrt[9401]) ArcCoth[101/Sqrt[
   9401]]))/4000

In[6]:=Plot[%3, {t, 0,1/1000}]

Out[6]=(*this code will plot the picture above*)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, I will study your answer in more detail.

Comment: @Jan you have done this before - you should not hand homework questions on a plate to anyone - that isn't what this site is about.